# Keyboard interrupts and os.system vs subprocess.call

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I'm writing a small CLI in python (with help of cmd module). Currently I'm trying to replace all `os.system` occurrences with `subprocess.call`.

The problem I'm facing is that if I run an external script with `os.system`, after I hit <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> only a subshell terminates (I get back into my CLI). When I run the same script with `subprocess.call` and hit <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, the script and my CLI both terminate the execution.

Is there a way to mimic the `os.system` behaviour with `subprocess.call`?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit as it clashed with the title change I made, but since I posted the same solution as an answer below, I think you now know the answer to that part. :-P (sorry for the conflicting edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch the keyboard interrupt in Python with an exception handler:

```
try:
    retcode = subprocess.call(args)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass # ignore CTRL-C
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to – forward – the keyboard interrupt to the subprocess? Because the subprocess might want to close some open resources.

Comment: @white_gecko: you can [send signals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal) to the subprocess, yes. Send a [SIGINT signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT).

Comment: So in this case I have to use a `Popen` instance instead of `call()`, is that correct?

Comment: @white_gecko yes; note that call is just a convenience method wrapping Popen; see the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/subprocess.py#l549) if you need to replicate the behaviour.