# os.system() disabling keyboard interrupt signal

Tags: python, signals, keyboard-events

I have the following line running in a loop, so at almost every point in time the program is running the system() call.

```
os.system(f"python3 {sys.argv[1]} < {sys.argv[2]} > measure-temp-output")
```

When I press the Ctrl-C (on Ubuntu) the KeyboardInterrupt happens inside the subprogram which is definately not what I want. Is there some way of enabling KeyboardInterrupt signal in the host process in a way that will not be disabled by system()?

This question is a reverse of what I ask:
[Keyboard interrupts and os.system vs subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739821/keyboard-interrupts-and-os-system-vs-subprocess-call)

Comment: Use `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.system()`. The shell is catching the signal.

Answer (score 0):

```
process = subprocess.run(["python3", sys.argv[1]], input=inputdata, capture_output=True)
capturedoutput = process.stdout
```